# Ember.js : Cannot bind array of data to forms

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember-data model named Customer who can have multiple phone numbers. In order to do so, my json feed return an array for the property phoneNumber, and everything is working fine.

The problem is that it seems i cannot bind this array to my template.

Indeed, if i create a property on my controller and iterate (via #each) on my template, everything is rendering pretty well, but when i start editing, the focus is lost after the first keystroke.

Here is a JSBin showing the problem : [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qayafiwu/2/edit)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using simple strings as your model. In order to 'change' a string, I think Ember removes the old one and splices in the new one. When that happens, a change in array composition causes DOM to redraw. That's why you lose focus.

You need to replace literal strings with some sort of model/object Ember can update.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {
      user: 'Foo',
      val: Ember.A([Ember.Object.create({content: 'Edit A'}),
            Ember.Object.create({content: 'Edit B'}),
            Ember.Object.create({content: 'Edit C'})])
    };
  }
});
```

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each list}}
      {{input value=content}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

[Live demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qayafiwu/10/edit).